# Why is だ being used at the end of the following sentence?

Tags: particles

This is the full sentence:

おかしいけど、中国人を理解するのは難しい。私は日本人を理解する方が簡単だ。

I think I was expecting something like です or よ.

I'm really confused about this だ.

Comment: Is your question about when to use だ vs です or do you simply not know what だ is?

Comment: だ. is informal です

Answer (score 2):

だ is the informal version of です. 簡単だ has the exact same meaning as 簡単です, but the former is less formal.

For example, 
私は猫が好き**です**よ has the same meaning as 私は猫が好き**だ**よ. But you would use です when talking to your 目上 (someone of higher social status) or in a formal situation, where you would use だ when talking to your friends

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of framing it this way, since there are many situations where だ and です are not interchangeable, but maybe you were hoping to not confuse them with more details.